# Perl/Linux filtering large file with content of another file

Tags: linux, perl, awk

I'm filtering a 580 MB file using the content of another smaller file.
File1 (smaller file)

```
chr start  End
1    123   150
2    245   320
2    450   600
```

File2 (large file)

```
chr pos RS ID A B C D E F
1   124 r2 3  s 4 s 2 s 2
1   165 r6 4  t 2 k 1 r 2
2   455 t2 4  2 4 t 3 w 3
3   234 r4 2  5 w 4 t 2 4
```

I would like to capture lines from the File2 if the following criteria is met.
`File2.Chr == File1.Chr && File2.Pos > File1.Start && File2.Pos < File1.End`
I’ve tried using awk but it runs very slow, also I was wondering if there is better way to accomplish the same?

Thank you.

Here is the code that I’m using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $bed_file = "/data/1000G/Hotspots.bed";#File1 smaller file
my $SNP_file = "/data/1000G/SNP_file.txt";#File2 larger file
my $final_file = "/data/1000G/final_file.txt"; #final output file

open my $in_fh, '<', $bed_file
        or die qq{Unable to open "$bed_file" for input: $!};

    while ( <$in_fh> ) {

     my $line_str = $_;

     my @data = split(/\t/, $line_str);

     next if /\b(?:track)\b/;# skip header line
     my $chr = $data[0]; $chr =~ s/chr//g; print "chr is $chr\n";
     my $start = $data[1]-1; print "start is $start\n";
     my $end = $data[2]+1; print "end is $end\n";

     my $cmd1 = "awk '{if(\$1==chr && \$2>$start && \$2</$end) print (\"chr\"\$1\"_\"\$2\"_\"\$3\"_\"\$4\"_\"\$5\"_\"\$6\"_\"\$7\"_\"\$8)}' $SNP_file >> $final_file"; print "cmd1\n";
     my $cmd2 = `awk '{if(\$1==chr && \$2>$start && \$2</$end) print (\"chr\"\$1\"_\"\$2\"_\"\$3\"_\"\$4\"_\"\$5\"_\"\$6\"_\"\$7\"_\"\$8)}' $SNP_file >> $final_file`; print "cmd2\n";

}
```

Comment: you're calling `awk` twice in a loop. No wonder why it's slow. Interested by a python solution?

Comment: sure, always wanted to learn python. thanks

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Actually only the 2nd line (`$cmd2=…`) calls `awk`. The `$cmd1=…` line only sets a string variable. We can see that from the different quotes used (`"` =assign) vs. ``(backtick)`` (=execute)). But no matter, you are right.

Comment: I wanted to try all of the suggestion but couldn't get to all of them. I used yours. thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that, and thanks. If follow-up questions pop up in the future let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the small file into a data structure and check every line of the other file against it.

Here I read it into an array, each element being an arrayref with fields from a line. Then each line of the data file is checked against the arrayrefs in this array, comparing fields per requirements.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

my $ref_file = 'reference.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $ref_file or die "Can't open $ref_file: $!";
my @ref = map { chomp; [ split ] } grep { /\S/ } <$fh>;

my $data_file = 'data.txt';
open $fh, '<', $data_file or die "Can't open $data_file: $!";

# Drop header lines
my $ref_header  = shift @ref;    
my $data_header = <$fh>;

while (<$fh>) 
{
    next if not /\S/;  # skip empty lines
    my @line = split;

    foreach my $refline (@ref) 
    {
        next if $line[0] != $refline->[0];
        if ($line[1] > $refline->[1] and $line[1] < $refline->[2]) {
            print "@line\n";
        }
    }   
}
close $fh;
```

This prints out correct lines from the provided samples. It allows for multiple lines to match.  If this somehow can't be, add `last` in the `if` block to exit the `foreach` once a match is found.

A few comments on the code.  Let me know if more can be useful.

When reading the reference file, `<$fh>` is used in list context so it returns all lines, and [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) filters out the empty ones. The [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) first `chomp`s the newline and then makes an arrayref by `[ ]`, with elements being fields on the line obtained by [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).  The output list is assigned to `@ref`.

When we reuse `$fh` it is first closed (if it was open) so there is no need for a `close`.

I store the header lines just so, perhaps to print or check. We really only need to exclude them.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, this time storing the smaller file in a Hash of Arrays (HoA) based on the 'chr' field:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $small_file = 'small.txt';
my $large_file = 'large.txt';

open my $small_fh, '<', $small_file or die $!;

my %small;

while (<$small_fh>){
    next if $. == 1;
    my ($chr, $start, $end) = split /\s+/, $_;
    push @{ $small{$chr} }, [$start, $end];
}

close $small_fh;

open my $large_fh, '<', $large_file or die $!;

while (my $line = <$large_fh>){
    my ($chr, $pos) = (split /\s+/, $line)[0, 1];

    if (defined $small{$chr}){
        for (@{ $small{$chr} }){
            if ($pos > $_->[0] && $pos < $_->[1]){
                print $line;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them into a SQLite database, do a join. This will be much faster and less buggy and use less memory than trying to write something yourself. And it's more flexible, now you can just do SQL queries on the data, you don't have to keep writing new scripts and reparsing the files.

You can import them by parsing and inserting yourself, or you can convert them to CSV and use [SQLite's CSV import ability](https://sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles). Converting to CSV with that simple data can be as easy as `s{ +}{,}g` or you can use the full blown and very fast [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS).

Your tables look like this (you'll want to use better names for the tables and fields).

```
create table file1 (
    chr integer not null,
    start integer not null,
    end integer not null
);

create table file2 (
    chr integer not null,
    pos integer not null,
    rs integer not null,
    id integer not null,
    a char not null,
    b char not null,
    c char not null,
    d char not null,
    e char not null,
    f char not null
);
```

Create some indexes on the columns you'll be searching on. Indexes will slow down the import, so make sure you do this *after* the import.

```
create index chr_file1 on file1 (chr);
create index chr_file2 on file2 (chr);
create index pos_file2 on file2 (pos);
create index start_file1 on file1 (start);
create index end_file1 on file1 (end);
```

And do the join.

```
select *
from file2
join file1 on file1.chr == file2.chr
where file2.pos between file1.start and file1.end;

1,124,r2,3,s,4,s,2,s,2,1,123,150
2,455,t2,4,2,4,t,3,w,3,2,450,600
```

You can do this in Perl via [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) and the [DBD::SQLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite) driver.

Comment: The link for the CSV import is too old. I found this other one: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/

Answer (score 0):

As said before, calling `awk` at each iteration is very slow. A full `awk` solution would be possible, I just saw a Perl solution, here's my Python solution as the OP wouldn't mind:

- create a dictionary from the small file: chr => list of couples start/end
- iterate through the big file and try to match the chr & the position between one of the start/end tuples.

Code:

```
with open("smallfile.txt") as f:
    next(f) # skip title
    # build a dictionary with chr as key, and list of start,end as values
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        toks = line.split()
        if len(toks)==3:
            d[int(toks[0])].append((int(toks[1]),int(toks[2])))


with open("largefile.txt") as f:
    next(f) # skip title
    for line in f:
        toks = line.split()
        chr_tok = int(toks[0])
        if chr_tok in d:
            # key is in dictionary
            pos = int(toks[1])
            if any(lambda x : t[0]<pos<t[1] for t in d[chr_tok]):
                print(line.strip())
```

We could be slightly faster by sorting the list of tuples and appyling `bisect` to avoid linear search. That is necessary only if the list of tuples is big in the "small" file.

Answer (score 0):

awk power with single pass. Your code is iterating the file2 as many times as there are lines in file1, so the execution time is linearly increasing. Please let me know if this single pass solution is slower than other solutions.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
    i = b[$1];        # get the next index for the chr
    a[$1][i][0] = $2; # store start
    a[$1][i][1] = $3; # store end
    b[$1]++;          # increment the next index
    next;
}

{
    p = 0;
    if ($1 in a) {
        for (i in a[$1]) {
            if ($2 > a[$1][i][0] && \
                $2 < a[$1][i][1])
                p = 1                 # set p if $2 in range
        }
    }
}

p {print}'
```

**One-Liner**

```
awk 'NR==FNR {i = b[$1];a[$1][i][0] = $2; a[$1][i][1] = $3; b[$1]++;next; }{p = 0;if ($1 in a){for(i in a[$1]){if($2>a[$1][i][0] && $2<a[$1][i][1])p=1}}}p' file1 file2
```